# SharePoint 2010 Help ICON Search is broken

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, help

I have a strange issue, When i Click on the Help Icon( top Right of the page with "?" sign), a new window pop up. If i try to search something i get the strange error **"Sorry, the page you're looking for can't be found."**

Things so far Tried.

1. Check the ULS logs after enable Verbose but no clue
2. Change the Help Settings but no luck
3. make sure page exist on all server(14 Hive).
4. Use Fiddle and found MSFT page thrwing the 404 error.(http://office.microsoft.com/serverhelp/searchresults14.aspx?qu=search&products=WSSEndUser&lcid=1033&SYSLCID=1033&UILCID=1033&Version=14)

here is error in window:

[image]

Comment: Tested in my environment, same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, MSFT update the URL at their end and now this stuff is working.Actually , `http://office.microsoft.com` was decommissions and redirected to `http://products.microsoft.com`. but for reason the redirect were not working, now MSFT fix the stuff at their end.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from [msdn](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/877a5986-c7e5-4b39-865d-484c3fd981b2/the-sharepoint-help-search-appears-to-be-broken-in-our-installation-of-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointsearch):

Here the feedback from Microsoft about my support case:

"Regarding your concern with SharePoint, I can inform you that this is a general concern, and that is not from your system or configuration. We are working on this issue to try to find a solution as quickly as possible. One way to solve temporarily, in some cases, this concern would be as follows (with SharePoint 2010 she normally works well with SharePoint 2013, only in some cases):

- Go to central admin url and replace "default.apx" by "_admin/privacy.aspx"
- "Display Help from external Web Sites as specified by each Help collection"  and click  No"

This will allow to use local SharePoint help, not online help untill wi fix this issue.

Comment: i saw this before, but it is for the sharePoint 2013 and my sharepoint 2013 farm have no issue. Only 2010 is broke. I just raise a services request with MSFT on it. lets see.